# sqlite wrapper in vc++?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm going to use a wrapper for opening *.sqlite* files and exploring their contents. here is the wrapper which I'm going to use:
[SQLite C++ Wrapper](http://int64.org/projects/sqlite-c-wrapper)

But I don't know how to use it! can anyone help me please?
Can you introduce me a library with a better documentation?

thanks so much

Comment: There are examples in that page.

Comment: The code is the documentation, and in the case for sqlite3x there isn't much code to begin with. It's rather easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

On this page you have both an updated [source](http://www.wanderinghorse.net/computing/sqlite/libsqlite3x-2007.10.18.tar.gz) and documentation in [pdf](http://www.wanderinghorse.net/computing/sqlite/overview-sqlite3x-sq3-2007.08.10.pdf) for sqlite3x.

http://www.wanderinghorse.net/computing/sqlite/